# document.getElementById() returns null when called from external jscript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have one aspx page,which looks like this and calls the 123.js file located within the solution.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="1.aspx.cs" Inherits="1"  ValidateRequest="false"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <script src="Scripts/123.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <tr>
     <td>Start DateTime</td>
     <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDateTime" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                                
     </td>
     <td>                                    
       <a href="javascript:_fnSet('this', 'txtStartDateTime', 'close=true,instance=single')">                                         
       <img src="Styles/imagesCA3B3R54.jpg" alt="IMG" style="border-style: none" />                                         
       </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
</asp:Content>
```

This function fnSet() is located in 123.js

123.js starts with

```
function _fnSet(e, sInputID, sCustom) {
    var oInput = document.getElementById(sInputID);
}
```

sInputID is getting the value 'txtStartDateTime' as string but,**This oInput returns null.**

Why it is happening so..???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in a ContentPlaceHolder. By default, ASP.NET places an extra identifier in front of the Control's ID when rendered to the client. This is known as the ClientID. You can change how the ClientID is generated by changing the ClientIDMode. Try changing the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to Static.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDateTime" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

If you're ever in doubt about what ID is being used on the client side, then view the page in your browser and view the HTML of the page that got generated.

In your web.config file, you can set ClientIdMode to be static by default.

```
<pages clientIDMode="static" />
```

Comment: I add `<pages clientIDMode="static" />` to my `web.config` when starting most projects.

Comment: Thanks @Papa, did not know about that configuration setting.

Comment: Thnx @msm8bball

Nw Calling function like
fnSet('this', 'ContentPlaceHolder1.txtStartDateTime', 'close=true,instance=single')

Its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The ID of txtStartDateTime is actually different. Have a look at the source code.

You can get the ClientID for example like this:

`document.getElementById('<%# txtStartDateTime.ClientID %>')`

Comment: No, he can't do that in an external JavaScript file.

Comment: but he can use `<%= txtStartDateTime.ClientID %>` in the aspx